# TCPSocket.h:35: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

Tags: c++, linux, c-preprocessor

I'm receiving "TCPSocket.h:35: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant" when compiling what I'm pretty sure was previously compiling code.

Line 35 is `TCPSocket(int port, bool vOutput, const int DIRECTORY_SIZE);`

from the below pasted class declaration

```
using namespace std;

class TCPSocket 
{
public:
#define SEND_BUFFER_LENGTH 80
#define DIRECTORY_SIZE 8192

    struct sockaddr_in myAddress, clientAddress;

    TCPSocket(int port, bool vOutput, const int DIRECTORY_SIZE);

    void buildTCPSocket(int newPort);
    void processMessage(char* bufferIn, int currentTCPSocket, int tcpSocket, bool verboseOutput);

    int getSocket1();
    int getSocket2();
```

Is either the define or the constructor definition an obvious error?

Edit:  Ok, so for those of you reading years in the future, here is the corrected constructor declaration:

```
 TCPSocket(int port, bool vOutput);
```

Then, the defined DIRECTORY_SIZE was used in the constructor definition.

Comment: btw - If the code you pasted is a header file then you shouldn't put `using namespace std;` in it.  Things like that can bite you badly in the future.  You should just use the `std::` qualifier as needed in header files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
TCPSocket(int port, bool vOutput, const int DIRECTORY_SIZE);
```

because it means

```
TCPSocket(int port, bool vOutput, const int 8192);
```

and this is not legal syntax. I guess you mean:

```
TCPSocket(int port, bool vOutput, const int nSize = DIRECTORY_SIZE);
```

Comment: Ha!  Thank you Kiril!  I don't know why I was even putting that in my constructor if I was defining it.  I just removed the parameter and used the defined DIRECTORY_SIZE in the body of the constructor.  Many, many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome (: I'd also recommend you to use `const int XXX = YYY` instead of using `define`-s (: